# Convolution of Pareto Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

Define $X$ ~ Pareto($a$) and $Y$ ~ Pareto($b$), meaning $f_X (x) = ax^{-a + 1}$ for $x \geq 1$ and $f_Y (y) = by^{-b + 1}$ for $y \geq 1$.

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, how would I find the density of $Z = X + Y$ and $W = Z - Y$.

Comment: It's not going to be nice; http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115291/what-distribution-results-in-adding-two-pareto-distributions

Comment: W=Z-Y? Sure about that?

Comment: I think my question is simpler than the one you posted a link to.

Comment: And yes, I'm tempted to think W = Z - Y is just X, but I don't think it is